# Labelling in MLP

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network, classification, label

I have a problem with the labeling on the MLP, first I thought it would be the same as the SVM labeling but after trying the code below :

```
 Mat labels(numSamples, 3 , CV_32FC1, Scalar(3,0));
    labels.rowRange(0, numcar - 1) = Scalar (1.0);
    labels.rowRange(numcar, numcar + numbus - 1) = Scalar (2.0);
    labels.rowRange(numcar + numbus, numSamples) = Scalar (3.0);
```

decide that the predictions on the same value even if I had to replace the image with another image. After I searched for it turns out there's a difference. The label must use a vector,I do not know how to label it using vectors because I newbie in this case.
below is the code for training

```
 Mat layers = Mat(4, 1 ,CV_32SC1);
int sz = data.cols;
layers.row(0) = Scalar(sz);
layers.row(1) = Scalar(10);
layers.row(2) = Scalar(10);
layers.row(3) = Scalar(3);
CvANN_MLP mlp;
CvANN_MLP_TrainParams params;
CvTermCriteria criteria;
criteria.max_iter = 1000;
criteria.epsilon  = 0.0001;
criteria.type     = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS;
params.train_method    = CvANN_MLP_TrainParams::BACKPROP;
params.bp_dw_scale     = 0.5f;
params.bp_moment_scale = 0.5f;
params.term_crit       = criteria;
mlp.create(layers, CvANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM);
mlp.train(data , labels ,Mat(),Mat(),params);
```

and predictions

```
Mat response(1, 3, cv_32FC1);
mlp.predict (sample, response);
cout << response << endl;
```

I here want to label cars, buses, and trucks.
Help me to solve this problem, thanks for attention